# Не устанавливаются плагины при запуске Jenkins в Docker контейнере

Tags: docker, jenkins

Запускал jenkins в docker контейнере командой:
`docker run -p 8081:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins`
 
После авторизации не удается загрузить плагины 
`Installation Failures. Some plugins failed to install properly, you may retry installing them or continue with the failed plugins`

При запуске Jenkins через `localhost:8080` такой проблемы нет и сам Jenkins более новой версии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать образ `jenkins/jenkins:lts`, а не просто `jenkins` т.к. он устарел (не обновлялся около 2 лет).